# Show final answer using sum (Sigma) on a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to show that :
[image]

I am not sure how i should get started because geometric sumdoesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you know about Riemann Sums?

Comment: It does sounds familliar, how should i use it to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})\frac{1}{n}$$

Rewrite your limit as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^2}\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\arctan(x)|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\arctan(1)-\arctan(0)$$